# Pain at back of knee when running

Tags: running, knees

I've had this issue for over a year now... after running about a mile, I feel an ache in the "back" of my right knee (the side away from my knee cap).  It seems to get worse whenever I take a step, but the ache goes away as soon as I slow to a walk.  I've tried both changing my footwear (I even tried barefoot running) and changing the way I run, but nothing helps.  I would really appreciate any insights or suggestions; it's frustrating not to be able to run long distances because of this issue.

EDIT: It's slightly above the joint line, more towards the outside, and fairly diffuse, but I'll try to clarify more the next time I go running. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't have any insight about this yet, but it could help others if you gave a more exact location of the pain. Is it above or below the joint line, to the medial (inside) or lateral (outside) side of your knee? Is it very localized, or more diffuse pain?

Answer (score 2):

You have full range of motion? No obvious swelling? No instability? You're still able to run on it, so it seems not too serious at the moment, although definitely something you would want to correct sooner rather than later.

Best diagnosis will come from a visit to a doctor, or a physiotherapist. They'd be able to assess you for muscle imbalances, etc.

To best prepare for an appointment, or even to be able to ask better questions on this website, you can take a look at this page from Mayo Clinic: http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/knee-pain/DS00555/DSECTION=preparing-for-your-appointment

Answer (score 1):

Sound a bit like what I had, which was diagnosed as [bursitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bursitis) - might be worth a bit of googling to familiarise yourself with it in case it helps. Be aware it is inflammation, not swelling. It was some time ago but I seem to recall there was a lot of ice involved, I also seem to recall having acupuncture to help. Mine was also almost exclusively during running. It is recoverable though, so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Patellofemoral pain syndrome could possibly be your issue. I came across this when doing some research on the tracking of the kneecap after having my MPFL (Medial Patellofemoral Ligament) replaced. Another name for PFPS is "runners knee". Many runners seem to notice similar pain to yours due to mistracking of the kneecap. Ligaments begin to wear down due to the continuous impact when running and may be causing your pain to last only until you begin walking again. Some research may be good so that you can identify any possible remedies for your pain. Hope this helps.

Comment: Patellofemoral pain syndrome refers to pain under the kneecap, where it meets the femur, not posterior knee pain, which is what Elliot is experiencing.